# how to get user input from antd Input.Password?

Tags: antd

I am trying to get user input from antd input.password field. Is it possible?

I didnt see any information on antd docs. I wonder if its possible

I am expecting a string for user input.password since i'll be saving them into local storage

Answer (score 1):

You can always use onChange method like **onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value) }**

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5283xn4vo4

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Input, Button } from "antd";

class PasswordToLocalStorage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    password: undefined
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Input.Password
          onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
          placeholder="Enter Password"
        />
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            if (this.state.password) {
              localStorage.setItem("password", this.state.password);
              alert("saved to local storage: " + localStorage.password);
            } else {
              alert("There is no password to save");
            }
          }}
        >
          Save to localStorage
        </Button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PasswordToLocalStorage />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: This will trigger the rerender, seems did not work as expect.@Shreyans Shrivastav